# Perl Data Structures: How to create an array ref from an array

Tags: perl

I have the following data structure:

```
@keys = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

And using a loop (`for`) from `1` to `4`, I want to create a new data structure like

```
$new = +{ key     => '1',
          meaning => '',
          time    => '', };
```

So, basically I would have in this case four `$new` data structures.

Do I need to use the map function?

Comment: You can use `map` or `foreach` although `map` is more common/idiomatic.

Comment: `@keys = [1, 2, 3, 4]` does not assign an array, it assigns an array of arrays (well, the first element of the array is an array).

Comment: @mpapec Rolled back your edit. You cannot fix code in the question unless the OP clearly says it was a typo.

Comment: yes im terribly sorry, i meant @keys = (1, 2, 3, 4);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Confusing question, but I think you problem is that

```
@keys = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

is probable not what you mean. It should be either

```
@keys = (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

or

```
$keysref = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

I'll assume the first. Then yes, you could populate an array of records with map

```
@records = map( {key => $_,meaning => '',time => ''}, @keys );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my @keys = (1, 2, 3, 4);

my @array = map +{ 
  key => $_,
  meaning => '',
  time => '', 
} @keys;
```

now `@array` has same number of elements as `@keys` and they are hash references.

Comment: Your edit on the main question is questionable. If the OP really has that in his own code, then it will be impossible for anyone to help him.

Comment: my guess was that OP did typo.

Comment: Yes, why else would you have done it. Still, it is possible it is not a typo.